# how to send an HTML email with an inline attached image with PHP

Tags: php, email, inline, attachment, html-email

I have a PHP script which sends an HTML email with an attached image. It works beauifully, however, I can't get the attachment to display in an `<img>` tag in the email body. The attached file is called `postcard.png` and the original filename on the server is `4e60348f83f2f.png`. I've tried giving the image URL as various things: `cid:postcard.png`, `cid:4e60348f83f2f.png`, `postcard.png`, and `4e60348f83f2f.png`. Nothing works.

I think the key part that I'm doing wrong is here, because this makes it a separated attachment instead of an inline attachment that I can use:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename="$fname" // i.e.: "postcard.png"
```

I've tried changing it to use a CID but I don't really know how to do that, and this didnt' work at all:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <$fname> // i.e.: postcard.png
```

Here's the full code: (It's based on [this code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#83491) from a comment in the php `mail()` page.)

```
<?php
$to      = "recipient@email.com";
$email   = "sender@email.com";
$name    = "Namename";
$subject = "An inline image!"; 
$comment = "Llookout <b>Llary</b> it's <br> the <b>Ll</b>andllord!<br><img src='cid:postcard.png'><br><img src='cid:4e60348f83f2f.png'><img src='postcard.png'><br><img src='4e60348f83f2f.png'>";

$To          = strip_tags($to);
$TextMessage =strip_tags(nl2br($comment),"<br>");
$HTMLMessage =nl2br($comment);
$FromName    =strip_tags($name);
$FromEmail   =strip_tags($email);
$Subject     =strip_tags($subject);

$boundary1   =rand(0,9)."-"
    .rand(10000000000,9999999999)."-"
    .rand(10000000000,9999999999)."=:"
    .rand(10000,99999);
$boundary2   =rand(0,9)."-".rand(10000000000,9999999999)."-"
    .rand(10000000000,9999999999)."=:"
    .rand(10000,99999);

$filename1 = "4e60348f83f2f.png"; //name of file on server with script
$handle      =fopen($filename1, 'rb'); 
$f_contents  =fread($handle, filesize($filename1)); 
$attachment=chunk_split(base64_encode($f_contents));
fclose($handle); 

$ftype       ="image/png";
$fname       ="postcard.png"; //what the file will be named


$attachments='';
$Headers     =<<<AKAM
From: $FromName <$FromEmail>
Reply-To: $FromEmail
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="$boundary1"
AKAM;

$attachments.=<<<ATTA
--$boundary1
Content-Type: $ftype;
    name="$fname"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename="$fname"


$attachment

ATTA;


$Body        =<<<AKAM
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--$boundary1
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="$boundary2"

--$boundary2
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="windows-1256"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

$TextMessage
--$boundary2
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="windows-1256"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

$HTMLMessage

--$boundary2--

$attachments
--$boundary1--
AKAM;

// Send email
$ok=mail($To, $Subject, $Body, $Headers);
echo $ok?"<h1> Mail sent!</h1>":"<h1> Mail not sent!</h1>";
?>
```

Comment: Use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org). Both allow in-line attachments with absolutely NO PAIN whatsoever, unlike what you're going through to build the MIME message from scratch.

Comment: It's not that it's not possible to do it by hand, but using Swiftmailer or PHPMailer would be way less cumbersome. -- possible duplicate of [Send email with PHPMailer - embed image in body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708153/send-email-with-phpmailer-embed-image-in-body)

Comment: @Marc B: I dunno, I pulled a hangnail typing once with PHPMailer, it was somewhat painful.

Comment: I don't really want to include a whole big thing like PHPMailer just for this single script. If I needed more email functionality I would use PHPMailer, but I just need to send one email with attachment here, and the script I already have is very close.

Comment: If you are rolling your own, adside from reading RFC documents, you can try making a simple example using your favorite email program and then opening the raw email in a text eitor to see how it was handled. (perhaps "Content-disposition: inline")

Comment: I have done this prior to posting the question: they have a unique code but when I tried to do the same thing it didn't work. The example I gave in the question is me trying to emulate what I saw in other emails regarding how it was handled.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally found the answer, which turns out to be remarkably simple. [This page](http://fil.ya1.ru/PHP_5_in_Practice/index.htm#page=0768667437/ch16lev1sec1.html) is what helped me figure it out, but I'll demonstrate the parts that I needed to get it done below.

First off, there's the creation of the boundary string, and the image, correctly encoded and chunked:

```
// Create a boundary string.  It needs to be unique (not in the text) so ...
// We are going to use the sha1 algorithm to generate a 40 character string:
$sep = sha1(date('r', time()));

// Also now prepare our inline image - Also read, encode, split:
$inline = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('figure.gif')));
```

In the HTML part of the email, the image is referenced like this (using the boundary string):

```
<img src="cid:PHP-CID-{$sep}">
```

Then you create another part of the email below the HTML part for the inline attachment, like this:

```
--PHP-related-{$sep}
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <PHP-CID-{$sep}>
{$inline}
```

...and that is that! Easier than implementing PHPmailer or any of the other libraries, if this is all you're doing. No doubt for more complicated task, you'll want to get one of those libraries.

Comment: I cannot attach according to this answer, I do like this: http://pastebin.com/z8LqAHCB

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using PHPMailer but since you say you don't want to I suggest this quick fix.

Put the absolute URL inside an img tag, if you do send an HTML email, it will work.

```
<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, however I am deleting the image from the server immediately after sending the email, so that will not work, as well as because many email clients don't allow hotlinking in emails.

Comment: Using this method the image will be blocked in various email clients