# How can I send an base64 image on a mail body with PHP?

Tags: php, image, email, base64

I'm trying to send an email with an image in base64 on the body with PHP using the code below, but the image never appears... If I change to an URL it works, but it doesn't with the base64... I tested the base64 on a new page only with `<img src=base64>` and worked too... What am I missing??

```
<?php
    // recipients
    $to  = $_POST['email'];

    // subject
    $subject = 'Test';

    // message
    $message = '
        <html>
        <head>
         <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <img src="'.$_POST['imageFromOtherPage'].'"/>

        </body>
        </html>
        ';

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 ?>
```

Here is my base64 image example: http://jsfiddle.net/28nP4/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried different things and the only way I found was uploading the image and getting the URL, I got that from this link: http://j-query.blogspot.in/2011/02/save-base64-encoded-canvas-image-to-png.html

It is very simple:

```
<?php
    // requires php5
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/');
    $img = $_POST['img'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

And this generates an URL, so, instead of using `<img src="'.$_POST['imageFromOtherPage'].'"/>`, I use the generated URL. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem, and finaly i resolved it. It might be helpful for you:
You can use SwiftMailer, but you must to add new Image TextHeader 'Content-Location'.
Here is the code:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()->setSubject($subject)->setFrom($fromEmail, 'Name')->setTo($toEmail)->setBcc($bccEmails);
/*get uniqueID from cid:uniqueID */
$imageID = explode(':', $message->embed(\Swift_Image::fromPath('pathToTheImage')->setContentType('image/png')))[1];

/*Add Content-Location to image header*/
/** @var \Swift_Image $image */
$image = $message->getChildren()[0];
$image->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('Content-Location', $imageID);
$message->setBody('here you will have some html with <img src=$imageID alt="Embed Image">', 'text/html');

$mailer->send($message);
```

Answer (score 1):

function for get all images url :

```
function getImagesFromMsg($msg, $tmpFolderPath)
{
    $arrSrc = array();
    if (!empty($msg))
    {
        preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', stripcslashes($msg), $imgTags);

        //All img tags
        for ($i=0; $i < count($imgTags[0]); $i++)
        {
            preg_match('/src="([^"]+)/i', $imgTags[0][$i], $withSrc);
            //Remove src
            $withoutSrc = str_ireplace('src="', '', $withSrc[0]);

            //data:image/png;base64,
            if (strpos($withoutSrc, ";base64,"))
            {
                //data:image/png;base64,.....
                list($type, $data) = explode(";base64,", $withoutSrc);
                //data:image/png
                list($part, $ext) = explode("/", $type);
                //Paste in temp file
                $withoutSrc = $tmpFolderPath."/".uniqid("temp_").".".$ext;
                @file_put_contents($withoutSrc, base64_decode($data));
            }

            //Set to array
            $arrSrc[] = $withoutSrc;
        }
    }
    return $arrSrc;
}
```

Comment: I am using a modified version of this, I go over the body of the template and I use the $message->embed from http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html and I replace the content of src="X" with the cid of the file created by this function.. works like a charm! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="'.$_POST['imageFromOtherPage'].'"/>
```

Your POST needs to start with `data:image/png;base64,` [to form a base64 encoded `data:` URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images).

But even if you fix this, it is well possible that the E-Mail client you're viewing the message in doesn't support the method at all. `data:`URIs are a relatively new phenomenon - at least in the chronology of E-Mail clients, most of which are still in the process of discovering that there's a technology called CSS. The tried and tested method for images in E-Mails is to embed the image as an inline attachment.

Here are some approaches that don't rely on a library: [Make PHP send an email with an inline image attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505673/make-php-send-an-email-with-an-inline-image-attachment)

However, using a library like Swiftmailer may take away a lot of pain. [Here is the appropriate Swiftmailer documentation.](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#embedding-inline-media-files)

Answer (score 0):

Try to test if $_POST['imageFromOtherPage'] contains the base64 , probably the code is too long for a Post, you would need to use  [php://input](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/wrappers.php) .

Comment: I tested, I wrote the content on a <P> tag and showed the right base64 content... It only doesn't "translate" as an image...

Comment: Are you sure it showed all the data? How the size of the img? If it`s 1mb or more the post can cut part of the base64 down