# How to send an image in the body of an email with PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to send an email with a screenshot as the body of an email. Normal text mail is being sent without any problem. `screenshot.png` is the image which I want to send.

```
<?php
  $to=$cust_email; 
  $cartTotal=$_SESSION["cartTotal"];
  $message = '<img src="screenshot.png">';
  mail($to,'Bill',$message,'FROM:xyz@gmail.com');
?>
```

I've also tried:

```
<?php
  $to=$cust_email; 
  $cartTotal=$_SESSION["cartTotal"];
  $message = '<img src="screenshot.png">';
  mail($to,'Bill','echo \'<img src="screenshot.png"/>\';','FROM:xyz@gmail.com');
?>
```

Comment: You'll need to look into sending a HTML email, rather than a plaintext one. You'll also need to include the image as an attachment.

Comment: is it not possible without the inclusion of an attatchment?coz we get so many mails with images in them!

Comment: You can link to it on a web server (`<img src="http://server/image.jpg">`), but a lot of mail clients won't automatically display those.

Comment: Here is the solution ... [stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390138/insert-image-in-mail-body

Comment: but embedding causes spam filters to let your email wait until server can send it to the emailclient. the clue is to design an email so that it will be nice with AND without pictures. in most cases @andrewsi tip is the right one, so the client decides if pic or not.

Comment: I guess another option would be to keep the image on your web server, and email out a link for people to click on? Though that then relies on people actually clicking.

Comment: This is the answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7511063/1064767