# how to send dataURL Picture via email

Tags: email, canvas, get, send, todataurl

For a web project, I want to send a picture which I get from a canvas via dataURL via email to upload it direct to tumbler. I can get the dataURL and download the picture with

```
function download() {
var dt = scope.toDataURL('image/png');
this.href = dt;};
```

is there a way to send this picture directly via email?

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a server component to receive the image and send it as an email. 
The following are ways to do it using PHP. There are examples using other languages if you search for it.

Part 1: Send to server:

[How to save a HTML5 Canvas as Image on a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server)

Part 2: Attach the image to the email and display inline

[how to send an HTML email with an inline attached image with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288614/how-to-send-an-html-email-with-an-inline-attached-image-with-php)

Comment: There's services like Mandrill that allows you to send emails client-side.