# Putting images in emails using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

How do I properly put images in emails using PHPMailer?

I have this code:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = "Issue:<br/>".$issue."<br/><img src=$img_data/>";
```

But when I send it to gmail it already looks like this:

[image]

I'm using URI's to store the image data. How do I link this image in PHPMailer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at this

question may be it will help you you can try this

[Send email with PHPMailer - embed image in body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708153/send-email-with-phpmailer-embed-image-in-body)

i hope it helps

Comment: this could have gone as a comment.

Comment: but i dont have option to comment

Answer (score 1):

Try to put an `'` in your img src property:

```
"<img src='$img_data'/>";
```