# php - use uploaded file as embedded image

Tags: php, html, forms, email, phpmailer

After searching Stack Overflow and the net for this answer, I am requesting assistance.  I  currently have a form that allows allows a user to upload a file.  It is my desire that once this file is uploaded, to then use it as an embedded image in an HTML email by phpmailer.  I can upload the file, but when I pass the info to the next page, the code is not picking up the file.

The form uses this label for the attachment (put spaces so code shows up):

```
<p>
  <label><span>Attachment</span>
    <input type="file" name="file_attach[]"/>
  </label>
</p>
```

When the form is submitted, the action calls email4.php (which then sends the mail to a local postfix server.  In this code, I reference the file as a variable:

```
$mypromo = $_FILES['file_attach'];
```

Then I use that variable as the embedded image:

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($mypromo, "my-attach", "tourney");
```

Once I send the email, the email comes thru, but no image.  Previously, the image shows up if I reference a file on the file system with a path/filename.  Is there a way I can use an uploaded file as an embedded image in phpmailer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email with PHPMailer - embed image in body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708153/send-email-with-phpmailer-embed-image-in-body)

Comment: RTFM: [handling post uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). `$_FILES['file_attach']` is **NOT** your uploaded file. it's metadata ABOUT your (maybe) uploaded file.

Comment: Marc...no need to rude.  I just started php like 5 days ago.

Comment: and for the record, I got it working just fine.