# how to send gif with php mailer inside email [not as attachment]

Tags: php, phpmailer

i want to send gif inside email with PHPMailer but I'm unsuccessful here's what I'm trying

`<img src="banner.gif" alt="banner"><br>`

but it doesn't work I don't know why

Comment: You'll need to specify an absolute url as rhe source. Otherwise which webserver should the email client fetch the image from? It does not know...the html is not being viewed inside your website, remember. Or you can try to embed it as a cid image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send email with PHPMailer - embed image in body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708153/send-email-with-phpmailer-embed-image-in-body)

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work out for me neither the thread nor the cid image. i don't know but my pc wasn't inserting image that is stored locally on my pc so what i did was to host the image some where like - https://telegra.ph (5 mb image limit) and copied the direct link of the image and did img src inside html! and boom, it worked.